# Tesseract OCR using java Tess4j - words with larger fontsize not detected

Tags: ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I'm a beginner with Tess4j, and I have a problem to extract text from png image, when there are a few words with a large fontsize, and bellow much more words with smaller fontsize (please see the photo, it will be clearer :) ).

For example, with this image, result of OCR is  : 
line 0 : lodsufoisuf sdqu kljsdhfksj quskjdfhl ksjqfhskl
line 1 : Qsidhfkquf ksdjfhlk sjdfh ijsdhf qlkjksdhf hjd 
[image]

While for this example, where there is more text with larger fontsize, result of OCR is  :
line 0 : Te e e e e e e e st 
line 1 : Iodsufoisuf sdqu kljsdhfksj quskjdfhl ksjqfhskl 
line 2 : Qsidhfkquf ksdjfhlk sjdfh ijsdhf qlkjksdhf hjd 
[image]

Here is my code :

```
    Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
    String inputPath="C:\\Users\\laogor\\Desktop\\souligne10.png";
    tesseract.setDatapath(".\\tessdata");      
    try {
        String stringOCR = tesseract.doOCR(new File(inputPath));
        String[] lines= stringOCR.split("\\n");
        int i =0;
        for (String string : lines) {
            System.out.println("line "+i+" : "+string);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (TesseractException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've tried to use method getSegmentedRegions, but words with larger fontsize are never detected.

I used to use Tesseract in Python, and it worked well.

Comment: Could be different [PSM mode](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage#tesseract---help-extra) or different tesseract version in python and java.

Comment: Thank you very much @DmitriiZ. ! Indeed I changed PSM mode to "PSM_SINGLE_COLUMN" and now it works fine.